# HTML: "onclick" does action every refresh

Tags: html, flask, button, onclick, jinja2

I don't know, why "onclick" action (on button or a - I've tried both) is done every refresh. When I open this page, I can observe actions connected with "set_active_experiment()" and "create_experiment()". I want to call these functions only when I click on link/button. Do you have any ideas?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Experiments</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="experiments">
        <h3>Your experiments:</h3>
        {% with experiments = get_user_experiments() %}
            {% if experiments %}
                    {% for exp in experiments %}
                        <a href="{{ url_for('experiment') }}"><button onclick="{{ set_active_experiment(exp) }}">{{ exp }}</button></a>
                    {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="{{ url_for('experiments') }}"><button onclick="{{ create_experiment() }}">Create new experiment</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your JS function.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the functions immediately, because you have wrapped them in curly brackets. This means, the code **is evaluated** and executed immediately.

```
<button onclick="{{ create_experiment() }}">Create new experiment</button>
```

If you want to call the functions on click, remove the brackets and add the calls **as string literals**:

```
<button onclick="create_experiment()">Create new experiment</button>
```

The same applies when calling `set_active_experiment()`.